# Transform Object in JavaScript to two object in Array

Tags: javascript

I have this object in my variable:

```
{ value1: '237.86', value2: '6.20' }
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
[
{name: 'value1', value: '237.86'},
{name: 'value2', value: '6.20'}
]
```

but I would like to do it in a very agile and nice way.

Comment: great. please add **your** try.

Comment: please add your code here so I can change it

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the object using `for..in` and push the value in an array

```js
let data = {
  value1: '237.86',
  value2: '6.20'
}
let newData = []
for (let keys in data) {
  newData.push({
    name: keys,
    value: data[keys]
  })
}
console.log(newData)
```

Comment: this is not correct with the guard-for-in principle.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the entries and map key and value as properties.

```js
var data = { value1: '237.86', value2: '6.20' },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(([name, value]) => ({ name, value }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First get key value pair of the object(in form of array) using [Object.entries](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/object/entries)

Then reduce it, like this:

```js
var object= { value1: '237.86', value2: '6.20' };
var entries= Object.entries(object);
var result = entries.reduce((acc, [key, value])=>{
 acc=[{"name": `${key}`, "value" : `${value}`}, ...acc];
 return acc;
},[]);
console.log(result)
```